# Warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing a face recognition and got an error when compiling it. 
My code to display the window frame is as follow:

```
int pos_x = std::max(face_i.tl().x - 10, 0);
int pos_y = std::max(face_i.tl().y - 10, 0);
putText(original, box_text, Point(pos_x, pos_y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2.0);
```

I got this error for the third line: `warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data`

How can I edit my code to solve this?

Comment: it's the last one, thickness is an int

Comment: how can i edit my code here please?

Comment: there is an edit button above these comments

Comment: Ok that solves it, now i got another line of error:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Ptr<class cv::FaceRecognizer> __cdecl cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer(int,double)" (?createFisherFaceRecognizer@cv@@YA?AV?$Ptr@VFaceRecognizer@cv@@@1@HN@Z) referenced in function __catch$_main$0
Is this related to that error as well?

Comment: no, it's not related, please start another question for this

Comment: I have to wait 4 days to ask a new question, can i know what error this could be? it doesn't show the line of error.

Comment: you forgot to link against opencv_contrib.lib

Comment: solved it thank u very much

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html), the seventh argument is

```
int thickness = 1
```

You're passing a floating-point literal `2.0`, which needs to be converted to `int`, and your compiler is configured to warn about such "narrowing" conversions. That's a good idea, since they often cause bugs.

The best solution is to pass an integer literal `2`, which doesn't need converting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's for the last argument, 2.0 try writing just 2